# How to debug Azure DevOps task PublishPipelineArtifact when one or more errors occurred

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build a pipeline that will 1. produce a file (jar) and 2. build a a Docker image with the output of the first job.  Following [this article's](https://medium.com/@brentrobinson5/containerised-ci-cd-pipelines-with-azure-devops-74064c679f20) [example](https://github.com/brent-robinson/azure-devops-container-jobs-example/blob/master/azure-pipelines-5.yml) approach, I understand can't use the first stage to build the Docker image because the Maven container I'm building inside doesn't have the docker engine.  Thus, I've set up a second job, but this means the build context isn't shared. Hence, I'm trying to use the `PublishPipelineArtifact` task (`publish` step) to then retrieve with the `DownloadPipelineArtifact` (`Download` step) but get the following failure (`System.Debug` is `true`). Have verified proxy is not blocking but don't really know how to proceed with debugging because the task appears to time out.

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'PublishPipelineArtifact'
##[debug]Evaluating: SucceededNode()
##[debug]Evaluating SucceededNode:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish pipeline artifact
Description  : Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
Version      : 1.2.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
Artifact name input: sampleTextFile
Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/mt/vsts/_work/45/s/publish-build-artifact/test.txt for build #11684
##[debug]Dedup parallelism: 192
##[error]One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
##[debug]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.Telemetry.BlobStoreApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender..ctor(IAppTraceSource tracer, Uri baseAddress)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.DedupManifestArtifactClientFactory.CreateDedupManifestClient(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, VssConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken, BlobStoreClientTelemetry& telemetry)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PipelineArtifactServer.UploadAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, Guid projectId, Int32 pipelineId, String name, String source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PublishPipelineArtifactTaskV1.ProcessCommandInternalAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, CancellationToken token)
   at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
```

Minimal pipeline config file I'm using (stripped out Java build and Docker build steps):

```
trigger:
- master

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: FirstJob
    pool:
      name: my-pool
      demands:
      - docker
    container:
      image: 'maven:latest'
    steps:
    - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish-build-artifact/test.txt
      artifact: sampleTextFile
  - job: SecondJob
    dependsOn: FirstJob
    condition: succeeded()
    pool:
      name: my-pool
      demands:
      - docker
    steps:
    - download: current
      artifact: sampleTextFile
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should have been using `PublishBuildArtifacts` [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) instead of `PublishPipelineArtifact` 
[task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts).

Comment: Good to know. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for this solution shared here . Please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, just a reminder :)

Comment: whats the issue here? Why can't I use `PublishPipelineArtifact`?

Comment: This answer is not correct. The Build task has been deprecated for a while now. We should be using the Pipeline task instead; the opposite of what was marked as the answer.